# How does the GitHub Developer plan work when working with multiple users?

Tags: git, github

I'm a little confused with the GitHub plans, I currently need to make a private repo and understand I need a paid plan.

However, I see the developer plan is only $7.00 a month and I get unlimited private repos and unlimited collaborators.

My confusion is that with the Developer plan how many people can I work with on a private repo, I know it says "Unlimited Collaborators" but are they able to push, commit, pull and merge code and all that? Is there a limit, because if so then why would you choose any of the other plans?

What is the difference between a collaborator and a user as well?

Comment: *"why would you choose any of the other plans"*? [The pricing page](https://github.com/pricing) lists the features, so: because you want those features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-user-and-organization-accounts/) explains the difference between a user and an organizational account.

In essence, the difference is:

A paid user account can create unlimited private repositories and *invite* any user to collaborate on the project.

A *team* account is an organizational account. This allows you to create an organization with multiple projects/repositories and manage the users within your organization.

The main difference here is the [granularity of permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-an-organization/).